# Data Binding for nested controls

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7, data-binding, windows-phone-8

I want to do search inside some books, then result of each book appears in separate item of pivot control. each one is represented by a separate LongListSelector control inside that PivotItem. Now I want to know should I assing `ItemsSource` for LongListSelector or for its parent which is a Pivot?

There is a dictionary for all books:

```
private Dictionary<string, List<Model>> ItemResources = new Dictionary<string, List<Model>>();
```

and a `List<Model>` for each book, which will be saved as a value inside `ItemResources` above.

this is what I do:

```
        foreach (var translation in ItemResources)
        {
            PivotItem pivotItem = new PivotItem
            {
                Header = translation.Key
            };

            LongListSelector lls = new LongListSelector
            {
                HideEmptyGroups = false,
                IsGroupingEnabled = false
            };

            lls.ItemTemplate = Resources["template"] as DataTemplate;
            lls.ItemsSource = translation.Value;

            pivotItem.Content = lls;

            ResultPivot.Items.Add(pivotItem);
        }
```

and the `template` is a reusable DataTemplate which I redproduce it for each longlistselector inside each pivotItem of the `ResultPivot`:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="template">
        <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,0" Orientation="Vertical">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="455" Margin="3,20,3,0">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="455" Margin="3,0,3,20">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

**The problem is that nothing appears on the screen after running. I saw in debugging, that the values are there, but it seems something is wrong with data binding. How can I solve it? thanks**

(this is a Windows Phone 8 App, but because the concept is the same for WPF and its wide community I added it too)

Comment: No, you tell us what's wrong with this code! What is your problem exactly? What doesn't work?

Comment: @Haspemulator sorry, I was about to change that part, you are right. Edited.

Comment: Don't you see any data bindings errors or warnings in debug output window?

Comment: Where is the DataContext for the template/control is being set? Are you properly implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: Oh, uh, Ohh. A brick please.. there is no ObservableCollection nor NotifyPropertyChanged!!, I just added a private field in the code behind and used it for `DataContext`. But I don't know how this was working a while ago?

Comment: thanks @PoweredByOrange for notifying. if you want add it as answer to mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UI has currently no way of knowing when the source changes. You need to either use an `ObservableCollection` or implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface to properly notify the UI when the source changes.